# Install Kali From Live System

Tags: installation, kali-linux, livecd

I am currently in the process of re-configuring my laptop, in order to allow me to use full-disk LUKS encryption (including the /boot partition) (See [this](http://www.pavelkogan.com/2014/05/23/luks-full-disk-encryption/) article).

The problem that I have run into is that in order to complete this process, I must encrypt the disk from a Kali live-system, and then install the operating system onto it WITHOUT REBOOTING.

Since Kali does not include a functioning installation script as a part of its live-build (unlike Ubuntu), how can I install it from the live-system?

Comment: kali's primarily designed as a livecd - I do wonder if you could 'simply' copy over the files, and manually rebuild the necessary stuff like initramfs from a chroot. Its still kind of a strange thing to do.

Comment: Why must it be a livecd system?  When you boot even the minimal iso, it is running linux during installation.  You should be able to set up the partitions manually if you want, by going to control-alt-f2 and dropping to the shell (and do the same at the end of installation to make sure grub has everything it needs)